# Can you set fstab to unmount then remount upon login

Tags: 14.04, mount, external-hdd, fstab

I have an external hard drive which only links up to my pc after it processes whats in fstab, would it be possible to make fstab unmount and then mount after I login so I dont have to go through the hassle of doing it myself everytime?